# Does a large control group lead to violation of assumption made to use difference-in-difference methods

Tags: difference-in-difference, control-group

Does a large control group lead to violation of assumption made to use difference-in-difference method? The control group is around 10 times larger than the treatment group.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no.

If the design is randomized, the only way this "hurts" you is that the comparative group is less precisely defined.

If the design is not-randomized and there are unadjusted interaction variables, the resulting estimates may be swayed compared to those obtained from a balanced design, but the results are simply standardized to different populations rather than one being "wrong" and the other "right".

If the variance is heteroscedastic and you do not use heteroscedastic consistent methods (unequal variance assumption in T-test or sandwich variance estimates in linear models), the tests may have incorrect SEs.

Comment: Is it a good idea (or even useful) to reduce the size of the control group, perhaps by using propensity scores?

Comment: @Egodym do you mean propensity *matching*? Maybe. In observational design, we don't refer to a "control group" per se, because you haven't *controlled* anything as in, say, an RCT. You can call this bigger set a "referent" group or an "unexposed" group in the observational setting. Matching is similar to covariate adjustment, reducing a sample size to a matched set won't do anything extra. I prefer to show the demographics and baseline chars (Table 1) with no matching, so that the reader understands the "sway" of variables btn groups, rather than eyeing their "balance".